# Copy radio button or text box values to dropdown Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been able to copy values from one dropdown menu to another using the below code. Is there a way to amend or  copy a selected radio button value or text box values to a dropdown menu?

Here is the code I have written:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var sel = $('.variation-selector :input');
    $('#pa_style').html($(sel).html());

    $(sel).change(function() {
        var var_performance = $(sel).val();
        $('#pa_style').val(var_performance).change();
    });
});
```

Comment: You want to add option to your drop-down (select) by using a text box ?

Comment: Either append or add an option should work. The dropdown selector is the woocommerce product variation option which i will hide and use the radio buttons to control it.